# What reasons make enthusiastic members not being active?

Tags: facebook, volunteers, nonprofit

I am a novice in community building, and am managing a group of ~8 volunteers for a nonprofit plan that I initiated. The group is running via Facebook chat. I understand that leader should be active, but what I don't understand is why enthusiastic members aren't active at all. Because they express that they really like to join the plan, they should be active as well? Or is it really necessary to ping every individual member to get their response? Why can't their enthusiasm replace my individual pinging?

Comment: Keep in mind, although a user might support your ideals and plan, they also have real lives, places to be in the real world. They cant be on 24 hours a day, 7 days a week to reply to you. I'm managing a 200+ user community for a nonprofit fangame, and Its successful because we respect each users culture, time zone, ideals and activity, which includes the amount of time they are online. Giving your community members their own freedoms is very important.

Comment: I understand. This is why I ask this question. There are surely successful volunteering projects that no one is paid? Or it's all come down to the number of volunteers?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that leader should be active

Yes, however beware of your activity. For nonprofits over 200 volunteers and various projects, it is impossible to handle every detail. Therefore it is important to have middle management reporting to you.

Communication is key and it should be adjusted to the various levels of the organisation.

> why enthusiastic members aren't active at all

There are only 24 hours in a day and people have lives outside their projects.

Projects where people don't benefit financially from it are harder to manage the various types of commitments.

If one was paying for 8H/Day one would already know that one could expect. In nonprofit's it is different, specially on the beginning when one doesn't have room for hiring hands.

And for that, communication is key. Talk with each member and understand their commitment, how much time can they commit to the organisation/project weekly/daily (not that this may also vary, but it serves as baseline).

Finally, I suggest you to be patient and appreciate every help people give.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, people are seeking leadership, organization and delegation of work, at least initially, to build motivation and momentum to start experiencing success as a group. Help them see the value of investing a wee bit of Individual effort and subsequently experience some collective success as a team.